# Prevent runtime crash for function instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)

Tags: ios, swift

## Swift 3.0

From what I found here is UIStoryboard always return non-optional instance in function `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`.

```
open class UIStoryboard : NSObject {
   ...
   open func instantiateViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController
}
```

The crash happen if we adding wrong `identifier` value, without noticed.
This case might happen in complex projects which have large number of controller in many storyboards, and a controller `StoryboardId` is missed.

The only solution I found is making a function to temporary create all controllers when start app delegate (this function should be called in debugging mode only).

```
func validateControllers() {
    guard let _ = xyzStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ABC") as? ABCViewController else {
        fatalError("fail in init controller ABC from storyboard XYZ")
    }
    ...
}
```

But I wonder if we could have another way to handle this situation. Or should I raise this issue to Swift team? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `guard` and `if let` to prevent from this crash, It will crash only if you write wrong `StoryboardID`.

Comment: Actually this is the problem that i want to solve: Wrong `StoryboarID` or lack of `StoryboardID`

Comment: Then you need to write about that in your question, because the code you have written in your question will prevent you from accessing `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing this answer to just to let you know how we handled the accidental typo(s) of a View Controller Identifier, which could lead to error when you try to create an ViewController from Storyboard(s) using view controller's identifier.

We had a complex project which had almost 15-20 ViewControllers, we didn't put them in a single storyboard instead we shared these VCs across multiple story boards and then we created an object called StoryBoardManager, which would create an VC from various storyboard(s) and hand it over to us.

We also created couple of enums to represent various storyboard(s) and viewController(s) inside.

It somewhat looks like this,

```
enum Storyboards : String {
    case main = "Main"
    case signup = "SignUp"
    case discover = "Discover"
    case utility = "Utility"
    case event = "Event"
}

enum ViewControllers : String {
    case login = "login"
    case onBoard = "on_board"
    case signup = "signup"
    case signupNavigation = "signupNavigaitonVC"
    case discoverNavigation = "discoverNavigation"
    case individualProfileSetUp = "individualProfileSetUp"
    case organizationProfileSetUp = "organizationProfileSetUp"
    case discover = "discover"
    case imagePickerMenuVC = "imagePickerMenuVC"
    case eventDiscoverMapNavigation = "eventDiscoverMapNavigationVC"
    case eventDiscoverMapVC = "eventDiscoverMapVC"
    case event = "event"
}

class StoryboardManager {

    static func storyboard(name:Storyboards) -> UIStoryboard {
        let aStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: name.rawValue, bundle: nil)
        return aStoryboard
    }

    static func viewController(storyboardId:Storyboards, viewControllerId:ViewControllers) -> UIViewController {
        let storyboard = StoryboardManager.storyboard(storyboardId)
        let viewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerId.rawValue)
        return viewcontroller
    }
}
```

We mainly did this to avoid the typo mistakes for the ViewController identifier(s), which would lead to an runtime error. You will add all the viewController(s) identifiers to ViewControllers enum and storyboard(s) names to the Storyboards enum as a enum case. We updated both the enums whenever we introduced a new storyboard or a new ViewController in any of the storyboards and this helped all the team members not to make the typo for ViewController identifier.

Then we created ViewController(s) using the below code,

```
let loginVC = StoryboardManager.viewController(.main, viewControllerId: .login)
```

HTH :)

Comment: Imo, the `StoryboardManager` isn't good enough, it lacks of the relation between controllers and storyboard. If I combine wrong `viewControllerId` with `storyboardId`, app will be crashed. So base on your idea, I improve a little bit to avoid this issue. :D

Comment: Sure thing. One suggestion would be make enum for each storyboard and then for those enums define viewcontroller Id(s) as cases for these enum(s). That may solve the problem upto an extent :D

Answer (score 3):

as far as i know there is no solution for preventing crashes like this. but this is a good thing and it's meant to crash like this to show you there is something wrong with your code and you need to fix them!

Comment: I made a trick to prevent this problem, after seeing your comment.

Comment: @nahung89 can you share it here?

Answer (score 0):

## Short brief

Currently, I have a complex project that have 5 storyboards, with 20 controllers. In my case, using storyboard segue seems not a good idea. Therefore, creating controller's instance from storyboard and make a transition by code is much better.

But the problem is that `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` always return `non-optional` instance, and it will be crashed if we put an invalid `identifier` (which didn't define in storyboard).

## Solution (Swift 3.0)

There are steps to prevent this problem.

1. In *.storyboard, use controller class name as `StoryboardID`
2. Create `UIStoryboard+Ext.swift` to define all storyboards &    controllers belong
3. Create `BaseViewController.swift` to define the initialization from storyboard
4. Create function to init all storyboards & controllers, to prevent crashing in runtime.

Download sample code from if you want to try yourself: https://github.com/nahung89/StoryboardPattern

## Detail (TL;DR)

*Step 1:*

[image]

*Step 2:*

```
extension UIStoryboard {
    
    enum Identifier: String {
        case main = "Main"
        case explore = "Explore"
        case search = "Search"
        case profile = "Profile"
    }
    
    static func name(for controller: UIViewController.Type) -> String? {
        var identifier: Identifier?
        switch controller.className {
        case HomeViewController.className:
            identifier = .main
        case ExploreViewController.className:
            identifier = .explore
        case SearchViewController.className:
            identifier = .search
        case ProfileViewController.className:
            identifier = .profile
        default:
            break
        }
        return identifier?.rawValue
    }
}

extension UIStoryboard {

    static func instanceFromIdentifier(_ identifier: Identifier) -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: identifier.rawValue, bundle: Bundle.main)
    }
    
    static func instanceFromName(_ name: String) -> UIStoryboard? {
        guard let identifier = Identifier(rawValue: name) else { return nil }
        return instanceFromIdentifier(identifier)
    }
    
}
```

*Step 3:*

```
extension UIViewController {
    
    var className: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
    
    class var className: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
    
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    
    static var controllerId: String {
        return String(describing: self) // return slass name, i.e "ExploreViewController"
    }
    
    static func instanceFromStoryboard() -> Self? {
        guard let storyboardName = UIStoryboard.name(for: self) else { return nil }
        return instantiateFrom(storyboardName: storyboardName)
    }
    
    private static func instantiateFrom<VC: UIViewController>(storyboardName: String) -> VC? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllerId) as? VC
        return controller
    }
}
```

*Step 4*

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func validateStoryboards() {
        guard
            let _ = UIStoryboard.instanceFromName(UIStoryboard.Identifier.main.rawValue),
            let _ = UIStoryboard.instanceFromName(UIStoryboard.Identifier.explore.rawValue),
            let _ = UIStoryboard.instanceFromName(UIStoryboard.Identifier.profile.rawValue),
            let _ = UIStoryboard.instanceFromName(UIStoryboard.Identifier.search.rawValue)
            else {
                fatalError("fail to init storyboard by name")
        }
        
        guard let _ = HomeViewController.instanceFromStoryboard(),
            let _ = ExploreViewController.instanceFromStoryboard(),
            let _ = ProfileViewController.instanceFromStoryboard(),
            let _ = SearchViewController.instanceFromStoryboard()
            else {
                fatalError("fail to init controller from storyboard")
        }
    }
}
```